# Resubscribing an observable if timeout exception occurs

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

i'm using retrofit to return an observable as a result of REST API call to server. Its very usual that a request timeout exception occurs and observable stops executing. How to resubscribe of retry if exception is of a specific type

```
myObservable
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Something> sub(){
        @override
        void onNext(Something something){
            //do something with something
        }
                    @override
        void onError(Throwable e){
            //retry and resend call to server if e is request timeout exception
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [retry](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) operator.

Example:

```
myObservable
    .retry((retryCount, throwable) -> retryCount < 3 && throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Something> sub(){
        @override
        void onNext(Something something){
            //do something with something
        }
                    @override
        void onError(Throwable e){

        }
```

In the example it will resubscribe when there is a `SocketTimeoutException` max 3 times.

or without lambda:

```
myObservable
    .retry(new Func2<Integer, Throwable, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Integer retryCount, Throwable throwable) {
                    return retryCount < 3 && throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException;
                }
            })
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Something> sub(){
        @override
        void onNext(Something something){
            //do something with something
        }
                    @override
        void onError(Throwable e){

        }
```

Comment: please use the syntax without lambdas. I'm new to programming and not familiar with lambdas yet

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to achieve. Maybe you can help me with this one too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309910/repeatedly-make-api-call-with-retrofit-and-rxjava