# Repeatedly make API call with retrofit and rxjava

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a retrofit observable:

```
@GET("something/")
Observable<Something> getSomething();
```

subscribing to it gives the response.

```
getSomething().subscribe(new Subscriber<Something>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Something something) {
                //update database of something
            }
        });
```

how can i make this call every 60 seconds so that i can update database accordingly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First please don't do it if you can avoid it. It's preferable to push the changes (GCM for example) instead of pulling to save battery and data.

To do this you can use a combination of `Observable.interval` and the `Observable.repeat` operator.

```
Observable.interval(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(n -> getSomething())
    .repeat()
    .subscribe();
```

Sorry about the lambdas.

Comment: Can you please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920829/polling-to-backend-api-in-regular-interval-for-certain-number-of-times-in-a-regu because in my case it should terminate with some condition. appreciated

Comment: Let's say, we send the request every ten seconds. How to skip the subsequent calls, If the server hasn't answered on the previous call yet?